# Port translation - how to scatter outbound traffic across random ports?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, firewall, port-forwarding

I would like to be able to PAT such that outbound traffic for a given destination port is translated to some random port within a range on a per-PDU or per-packet basis.

The intention is that outbound traffic will be 'scattered' across the specified port range, similar to the principle of frequency hopping for radio transmission...  Preferably, I would like this to be transparent to upstream applications.

An example scenario would be a file transfer utility that sends a stream of packetised data to host with destination port 9080.  I would like to translate (perhaps even listen on localhost TCP port 9080) all traffic for a given host with destination port 9080 such that each packet goes out to the given host on a random port between, say 49000 to 50000.

To further clarify, I am not concerned with the source port from which traffic originates.  My intention is to have a sender that sends on *destination* port 'N' across a link to a receiver that is listening for traffic coming in on destination port 'N'.  After traffic leaves the sender, I want to randomize the destination port to a value within a known range... so a bunch of traffic will be seen over the wire with random destination ports... because the range is known, this traffic can then be re-translated to destination port 'N' by the firewall or similar at the receiver end.

Similar to:

```
[N]         = packet with destination port 'N'

[A <=N=> B] = packet with destination port between A and B

                                     /--[49000 <=N=> 50000]--\
SENDER --[N]-[N]-[N]--> (RANDOMISER)<---[49000 <=N=> 50000]--->(UNDO)-[N]-[N]-[N]-->RECEIVER
                                     \--[49000 <=N=> 50000]--/
```

I am looking to achieve this on both Windows and Linux platforms.  So far I am unable to find much in the way of useful information or suggestions, and so any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: am I understanding you, that you want every segment in a TCP connection to appear to come from a different port?

Comment: Thanks again for replying.  In fact, I want the opposite - I want every tcp segment to be destined for a different port.  I can handle redirection / retranslation at the receive side...

Comment: Well, you would need a custom PAT implementation to do it in a way that doesn't break TCP logical circuit connections. TCP by default defines a connection as a coordinated flow of segments between a pair of ports, with negotiated SNY/ACK values, so it can reorder as needed, notice missing segments to signal for a resend, and particularly in the case of NAT/PAT, that each end can tell that the segment is part of an established connection in accordance with Stateful Packet rules. A standard PAT implementation would treat each segment as unsolicited, and not part of an established connection.

Answer (score 0):

Windows assigns outgoing client connections to the first available TCP port > 1024 by default, unless the application specifies a port for connection.

you can change the starting port for this behavior, using the netsh commands shown here: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsServer2008/AdminTips/Admin/DefaultDynamicPortRange.html so you can set it to start at 40000 and the end at 50000if you like.

In linux, you can change the starting/ending port behaviour using  sysctl:
http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/

That said, you will not be able to select ports randomly, using these techniqies. I would be surprised if you could alter that functionality without changing OS source code, and many application would not play nicely with the functionality.

hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Frank - many thanks for responding.  If I have understood correctly, you are describing the allocation of an arbitrary local source port from which the communication originates, rather than the destination port which traffic is sent to?  

I believe I may need to clarify my question, and so will edit this accordingly.